# Index template with wildcard type names

Tags: elasticsearch

As we can read on [this section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) from the official documentation, we can set wildcards in the index names, I have tested it and works fine, but, there is any way to can do the same with the type names?. For example

```
{
    "user": {
        "template": "user-*",
        "settings": {
            "index.number_of_shards": 5,
            "index.number_of_replicas": 1
        },
        "mappings": {
             "info": {
                 "dynamic": "strict",
                 "properties": {
                     ...
                 }
            }
            "more": {
                 "template": "more-*",
                 "_parent": {
                    "type": "info"
                 },
                 "dynamic": "strict",
                 "properties": {
                     ...
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thise example doesn't work, sure, but I hope that there is another way to can do it.

UPDATE:
Second aproximation

```
{
    "user": {
        "template": "user-*",
        "settings": {
            "index.number_of_shards": 5,
            "index.number_of_replicas": 1
        },
        "mappings": {
                "info": {
                    "dynamic": "strict",
                 "properties": {
                        ...
                    }
               }
            "more-*": {
                    "_parent": {
                    "type": "info"
                 },
                    "dynamic": "strict",
                 "properties": {
                        ...
                    }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

But when I try to create that type "more-2015" inside "user-0" index (/user-0/more-2015/) get the next exception:

> org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: Can't specify
>   parent if no parent field has been configured

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish in the second section of your mapping field?

Comment: I want to match all types "more-*" created inside the "user-*" indexes with the mapping named "more".

Comment: unfortunately you cannot set a wildcard in type name

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have different types with the exact same mapping ?

[From the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/mapping.html#mapping)

> A type in Elasticsearch represents a class of similar documents. A type consists of a name—such as user or blogpost—and a mapping. The mapping, like a database schema, describes the fields or properties that documents of that type may have, the datatype of each field—such as string, integer, or date—and how those fields should be indexed and stored by Lucene

You wouldn't have different classnames, with the same structure.  Has I said in my comment, you cannot have  a wildcard in type name, because it wouldn't make any sense.

From what I can see, you use year as a dimension. Have you considered having one index per year, and your types info & more-info ?